# Simplificar código en python

Tags: python-3.x

**Como puedo simplificar este código :**

```
    for buscando_letra in range(logitud_palabra):
        if(adivina_letra == letras[buscando_letra]):
            total_encontradas +=1
            indice_letra = letras.index(adivina_letra,buscando_letra)
            posicion_letra.append(indice_letra)
            guiones.pop(indice_letra)
            guiones.insert(indice_letra,adivina_letra)
```

Gracias..!!

Answer (score 0):

Primero crie guiones:

```
guiones = {i: c for i, c in enumerate(letras) if c == adivina_letra}
```

Después los datos serán deduzidos de este:

```
total_encontradas = len(guiones)
indice_letra = max(guiones)
posicion_letra = sorted(guiones)
```